# unix/linux shell (command) script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I'm making a command shell script name *csbin*. Here is my *csbin* file:

```
for (( i=1; i <= $#; ++i ))
do
    b+="\$$i "
done

echo my_program $b
```

If I run my shell script as given below:

**./csbin hello everyone welcome here**

Here is output what i get:

```
my_program $1 $2 $3 $4
```

But i want output must be look like:

```
my_program hello everyone welcome here
```

Actually I want to pass all argument (except command name *csbin*) to ***my_program***. How can I do this? can anyone help me?

Comment: Your immediate error is using `\\$i` when you mean `${!i}` but the loop is quite unnecessary; the arguments are in `"$@"` (notice mandatory double quotes!)

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks. @tripleee